# Remove multi indexes from linq list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to remove multiple indexes from a linq list, I am using the following code:

```
slidePart
         .Slide
         .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>()
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(pic => pic.Remove());
```

There are 3 elements in the List and now what I want is to select only the 1st and 3rd element then execute ForEach to remove them.

**[Edit]**

The Problem is also that Indexes are dynamic.

Comment: first of all - you cannot modify collection via `Foreach` loop. If you have a collection of Indexes you want to remove just iterate throught them calling `slidePart.RemoveAt(Index)` (take care that indexes start from 0)

Comment: @Nogard I would also point out that you would need to remove the elements in reverse order, starting with the highest index.  Otherwise each remove would shuffle the indexes around and cause the incorrect elements to be deleted (Item(0) is removed causing Item(2) to become Item(1), etc.)

Comment: @Mike indeed, should have specified that explicitely in my first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var toRemove = new int[] { 1,2,.... };

    slidePart.Slide
        .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>()
        .Where((x, i) => toRemove.Contains(i) )
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(pic => pic.Remove());
```

If your list (*toRemove*) is large, you may reduce the search time (of *Contains*) from O(n) to O(1) by changing the declaration of `toRemove` a little bit

```
var toRemove = new HashSet<int>(new int[] { 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use *indexed* overload of [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) filter to select items at multiple indexes. Keep in mind that LINQ only gives you a view of the collection - another collection instance - so you cannot modify the original collection. It may be possible if the `Remove` method handles removing an item from its owner, but that would be a very special and rare case.

In your case, getting the items would look like this

```
var toRemove = new[] { 1, 2, ... };

var itemsToBeRemoved = slidePart.Slide
    .Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>()
    .Where((pic, index) => toRemove.Contains(index))
    .ToList();
```

But to be able to remove the items, you may need to call some sort of `Remove` method on the `Descendants` collection itself or there may be completely different approach needed in your scenario.

Comment: `.ToList()` in the question creates completely new collection and can be enumerated safely on it.

Comment: You're right, I'm more concerned about the `pic => pic.Remove()` part.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan OP's code is completely safe. It doesn't enumerate on the original collection.

Comment: Edited as well. L.B, maybe my answer was unclear, it is of course possible to enumerate again on the new collection and remove from the original one - it's just another story, not a simple part of one query over the original collection.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan But you repeat what I write as an answer. Now I'll change my answer a little bit for performance reasons. Please don't copy this.

Comment: @L.B I added that to make my answer relevant to the question. Your other edit is just performance issue, no need to "copy" that (as if you had a copyright on it anyway).

Comment: @HonzaBrestan It is not related with copyrights. It is more related to respect the other's work . if you like someone's answer, upvote it not copy it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 slidepart 
.RemoveAll(x => toRemove.Contains(slidepart.IndexOf(x))).ToList();
```